# Python Coverage turns top-level package name into period

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest, pytest-cov

I have a project laid out like this:

```
proj/ex_secure/__init__.py
proj/ex_secure/base.py
proj/ex_secure/metrics.py
proj/ex_secure/keys.py
proj/tests/test_base.py
proj/tests/test_metrics.py
proj/tests/test_keys.py
proj/.gitignore
proj/.pep8
proj/README.rst
proj/setup.cfg
proj/setup.py
```

If I run `pytest` like this:

```
pytest -s --junitxml=pytests.xml --cov-report xml --cov-report term-missing --cov-branch --cov=ex_secure
```

Then the top-level package in the resulting `coverage.xml` is named `.`:

```
<package branch-rate="0.4722" complexity="0" line-rate="0.6801" name=".">
```

But if I call `pytest` like this:

```
pytest -s --junitxml=pytests.xml --cov-report xml --cov-report term-missing --cov-branch --cov=ex_secure.base --cov=ex_secure.metrics --cov=ex_secure.keys
```

Then the top-level package is correctly named `ex_secure`:

```
<package branch-rate="0.4722" complexity="0" line-rate="0.6801" name="ex_secure">
```

It's an okay workaround for now, but it's not ideal. If I add more packages, I have to keep enumerating them (or they'll be missing on the coverage report). Additionally, `__init__.py` isn't covered using this mechanism.

What am I doing wrong here?

***UPDATE 1:***

If I run Python Coverage directly instead of using `pytest-cov`, it works as expected:

```
coverage run --branch --source=ex_secure -m pytest -s --junitxml=pytests.xml
coverage xml
```

Then:

```
<package branch-rate="0.4722" complexity="0" line-rate="0.6771" name="ex_secure">
```

***UPDATE 2:***

If I run PyTest as I originally did, but then re-generate the XML report with Python Coverage directly, the re-generated report gets corrected, but has slightly different numbers:

```
pytest -s --junitxml=pytests.xml --cov-report xml --cov-report term-missing --cov-branch --cov=ex_secure
coverage xml
```

Then:

```
<package branch-rate="0.3058" complexity="0" line-rate="0.4769" name="ex_secure">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a rather nasty two-part bug that spans both Py-Coverage and PyTest-Cov. It is described in detail on the [PyTest-Cov GitHub](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/175) and the [Py-Coverage BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues/613/coverage-xml-report-with-sources-argument).

In short, calling `coverage xml` from the command line doesn't allow you to pass in `sources`, so most people don't see this problem, but you can pass in `sources` when using the Python API for Py-Coverage, and that API does not correctly handle the `sources` attribute. PyTest-Cov, meanwhile, uses the Python API for Py-Coverage, so when you call PyTest-Cov with `--cov=xxxx` and `--cov-report xml`, you end up with this problem.